# How could I delete an item from an array by the item's name?

Tags: javascript

Like I have an array **Array('one', 'three', 'two');**, and, say, I want to delete the item three, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = ['one', 'three', 'two'];
a.splice(a.indexOf('three'), 1);
alert(a);
```

for browsers that don't support indexOf there's a workaround
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf#Compatibility

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your args to `splice` are messed up. Should be the other way around: `a.splice(a.indexOf('three'), 1);` See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Splice

Answer (score 1):

```
function RemoveArrayValue(arr, val)
{
   var result = [], //empty array
   j = 0, i, len = arr.length;

   for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      if(arr[i] != val)
         result[j++] = val;

   return result;
}
```

BTW:

the indexOf method is not part of the Javascript Array object under IE (also not part of IE8), but of the String object. If you want the indexOf method to be part of the JS Array object you must declare this in your code:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(val)
    {
       for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i)
          if(this[i] === val)
             return i;

       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` is part of the `Array.prototype`, but it hasn't been implemented by all browsers (IE lacks of it) this method is part of the ECMAScript 3rd Ed. Standard, and you should check if a native `Array.prototype.indexOf` exists before overriding it, because native implementations are lightning fast...

Comment: Right! Thank u 4 the comment. I updated the code above as u suggested. :)